# How to create a loop playlist through programming

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a music player with a loop playlist through qt.But the code just only play the last wav file which I add.I can't use QMediaPlaylist because it has deleted in qt6.

```
void MainWindow::OnPlayVoice(QString filename)
{
    QString path="voice/";
    pQMediaPlayer->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(path+filename+".wav"));
    pQAudioOutput->setVolume(50);
    pQMediaPlayer->play();
}
void MainWindow::Replay()
{
    for(int i=0;PianoRecorder.key_order[i];i++)
    {
        string x;
        x+=PianoRecorder.key_order[i];
        QString qx=QString::fromStdString(x);
        OnPlayVoice(qx);
    }
```

Comment: Not clear what is `PianoRecorder`, why is `PianoRecorder.key_order[i]` used as stop condition in your `for` loop, how you create your list, and how you call `Replay()`.

Comment: This example obviously implements playlist: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html